# When can Request.Url be null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, resharper

In my controller code I am using: `Request.Url.<Something>`. ReSharper suggests that `Request.Url` can be null.

So, **when exactly can `Request.Url` be null?** I am not talking about testing, I am interested only about an Application that is live / has already been deployed.

Please note that I have not received any `NullReferenceException`s from using `Request.Url` up to this point.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`HttpRequestBase` is a class and ReSharper sees it as an actual Class, nothing more (theoretically, it can be `null`). So it does not analyze the usage of this specific Class.

In reality, I think that `Request.Url` will *never* be `null`, so just ignore ReSharper in this case.

Comment: Good shout, I think sometimes resharper can be a dangerous thing but without it I perhaps wouldn't have read this. Cheers guys. P.S hugs and kisses for resharper :)

Answer (score 17):

Actually a `NullReferenceException` can occur when using `Request.Url`. When you create your own base controller class from which other classes derive, `Request` will be null. Or when using ActionMailer with ASP.NET MVC you'll have to create a controller class that derives from `MailerBase` (which also causes `Request` inside this controller to be null).

Alternative: use `HttpContext.Current.Request` or check whether `Request` is null.

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request :)

Comment: FYI: Request.Url is not null if your base controller inherits from Controller, i.e. BaseController : Controller

Comment: Just be aware that using `System.Web.HttpContext` can interfere with testing that needs to mock the `HttpContext` (since there's no actual IIS request occurring during unit testing). See [HttpContextBase vs. HttpContext](http://www.splinter.com.au/httpcontext-vs-httpcontextbase-vs-httpcontext/) and [How to get HttpContextBase object from HttpContext.Current](http://thecodersperspective.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-get-httpcontextbase-object-from.html)